# Livestock Diseases in Indiana

Tags: data-request, animals, agriculture

Does anyone know of any datasets regarding livestock diseases in Indiana? I am a GIS student in need of a unique data source; as I do not work in GIS yet, I have chosen a topic in a field in which I want to work. Specifically, I'm looking to locate a source from which I can practice manipulating raster data (comparing, reprojecting, clipping, extracting, making mosaics, creating TINs and 3D renderings, etc.). Data in any format is sought.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a pretty specific dataset that may or may not be available (I know, that's the whole point of posting on here) and while I dont know where to find this exact dataset, here are some datasets that might help you get to your end goal and/or create proxy/synthetic data for you to practice analysis on.

- The Indiana Geographic Information Council (IGIC) has an agriculture census at http://data.indianamap.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8eb957fc6efa4ad692f853da0fec3079_0 which has a row per county and many different attributes including crops and livestock. Available as ESRI Shapefile, CSV, and more.
- The country of Kenya has open data by district with the count of different types of livestock at https://www.opendata.go.ke/Agriculture/Census-Vol-II-Q-11-Livestock-population-by-type-an/qbvv-8bjk . Available in API, CSV, JSON, GeoJSON, etc. You might be able to use this with other information to get the number of sick/diseased livestock per district
- Not quite open (PDF format :[) but data.gov showed some results about a yearly Avian Influenza Surveillance Project in the state of Montana which might be helpful https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=%22Avian+Influenza+Surveillance+Project+Report%22&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc

Answer (score 1):

USDA's National Institute of Food and Agriculture (NIFA) has data like this; start at the:
[NIFA Data Gateway](http://portal.nifa.usda.gov/enterprise-search/project_details)
Enter "livestock diseases indiana" in the Search Projects form control input results in:
[68 Projects with terms "livestock diseases indiana"](http://portal.nifa.usda.gov/enterprise-search/?site=CRIS_FACETS&from_site=NIFA&client=reeis_facet&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=reeis_facet&filter=0&getfields=Progress+Year.Knowledge+Area.Science.Subject.Type.Keywords.FDC.State.Grantee+Type.Project+Type.Sponsoring+Agency.Award+Amount+Range.Grant+Award+Year&q=livestock+diseases+indiana)
Second result looks like a hit:
[Prevalance & Molecular Relationship Between Fecal Culture, Elisa & Colostrum Culture for Johne's Disease in Indiana Dairy Cows](http://portal.nifa.usda.gov/web/crisprojectpages/0205694-prevalence-and-molecular-relationship-between-fecal-culture-elisa-and-colostrum-culture-for-johnes-disease-in-indiana-dairy-cows.html)
Not sure about this resource (I know they do import/export data), but [USDA's APHIS (Animal and Plant Health Inspection Service)](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/home/)  may also include data you can use.